# Is there an elegant way of combining the Python vars() and filter() functions to display the values of a subset of variables?

Tags: python

Is there a way of displaying the names and values of a subset of variables in a string?

The following filters the names of certain variables, but is there an elegant way, within one line, to show the values of the variables too?

```
>>> result=list(filter(lambda x : x in ['a'], vars()))
>>> result
['a']
```

Comment: What do you mean, exactly, when you use the term _variable_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be done:

```
>>> a = 123
>>> result = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] in {'a'}, vars().items()))
>>> result
[('a', 123)]
```

But imo a much more elegant way is to use a list comprehension:

```
>>> a = 123
>>> result = [(name, value) for name, value in vars().items() if name in {'a'}]
>>> result
[('a', 123)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `vars().items()` to get the keys and values.

But you can't use `filter()` becau

```
result = list(filter(lambda x: x[0] in ['a'], vars().items()))
```

This will return

```
[('a', 'value_of_a')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Best thing I've managed so far:

`foodict = {k: v for k, v in vars().items() if k in ['a']}`